# Swap list box content to other listbox in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to Move ListBox1 content to ListBox2

I used the following syntax

```
Listbox2.items.add(listbox1.items)
```

It's not showing any error

Comment: The `Add` method adds one item. If you want to add multiple items in one go you need to call `AddRange`, to which you need to pass an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop:

```
For each item In Listbox1.Items
    Listbox2.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

If you really want to swap the content you need backups and to clear them:

```
Dim backup1 = Listbox1.Items.ToArray()
Dim backup2 = Listbox2.Items.ToArray()
Listbox1.Items.Clear()
Listbox2.Items.Clear()
Listbox1.Items.AddRange(backup2)
Listbox2.Items.AddRange(backup1)
```